# Woocommerce custom plugin, WC_Order error

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

inside a custom plugin placed this code to get an order:

```
 global $woocommerce;
 $order = new WC_Order(5273);
```

(and i have the order with 5273 in the database), but the result is:

**Fatal error**:  Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in **D:\www\htdocs..\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\class-wc-order.php** on line **83**

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem. I called the code above inside the initialization hook, like this:

```
add_action('init', 'my_init', 1);
function my_init(){
    $order = new WC_Order(5273);
}
```

the last argument in add_action is the priority and that was the point. 1 is the highest priority and my function is being called before the taxonomy registrations. I changed 1 to 100 and the code is working perfectly.